# Deep eager fetching while doing JPA2 criteria queries

Tags: jpa-2.0, criteria

Idea seems pretty simple, I have an object relation graph like this:

```
    A >Many2One> B >ManyToOne> C
```

I want to make a criteria query that will load all relevant data for A, in SQL I would do consecutive left joins to get data from a, b, c in one row. I can't find a way to do this in Criteria API. I can make .fetch for root object (A) but how to fetch object further down the graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `fetch(A_.b, JoinType.LEFT)` on your `Root<A>`. This will return a `Fetch<A, B>`, and you may then call `fetch(B_.c, JoinType.LEFT)` on this `Fetch<A, B>`.